# Reading a file in Node using a configuration process env variable

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to read a file in app/resources/xml/data.xml.  I attempted to read the file using several attempts but it seems I cannot read the file without appending the app directory in the path process.env variable. Is there a way to read a file relative to where you are in the application? I want to read the file /resources/xml/data.xml from the file-utils folder.

My application structure is:

```
app
  +---resources
      +--xml
      +-------data.xml
  +---file-utils
      +---- fs-utils.ts
```

Currently, I am trying:

```js
         export async function readData(fileName: string){
            try {
              const data = await fs.promises.readFile(fileName, 'utf8')
              return data
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return null
            }
        }
```

I can read the file by setting

```
    export DATA_PATH=../app/resources/xml/data.xml
```

I would like to be able to also allow DATA_PATH=/resources/xml/data.xml if possible

I access the environment variable as follows:

```js
             let file = process.env.DATA_PATH || ''
             if(file.trim().length === 0){
               throw new Error('File is a required field')
             }
             processData(file);
```

Comment: What is the _working directory_ when you run your app? Ie, which directory are you in when you start it?

Comment: Please show how you are accessing the environment variable and calling the `readData` function

Comment: I have added the code showing how I access the variable.